# Kubuntu proprietary drivers vs open source

Tags: drivers, kde, performance, proprietary

Which driver has better performance with the KDE desktop environment for kubuntu 11.10? Laptop integrated AMD Mobility Radeon HD 3200.

Comment: Please provide more information regarding video card or whatever hardware you want to know about. But for the most part the proprietary drivers deliver the best performance in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience proprietary drivers gives better performance. Given so little information it's hard to give a more in depth answer.

Comment: I agree, in general the proprietary drivers will give better performance, although not always hassle free. If the open source driver gives acceptable performance, the open source drivers are easier t maintain and you get support for them from the open source community.